# Linux (ubuntu) as NAS permission help needed

Tags: windows, ubuntu, samba, network-attached-storage, file-permissions

Ok, i have a user "nas" on my ubuntu server. In his home directory i have a "shared" folder but I also want to let a user create their own folder at this level for personal use. so any user that logs in can create a folder that they will have exclusive (unreadable by anyone else) access to, and if they want to share something they put it in the shared folder. How would I achieve this? I was reading about the permissions on the /tmp directory using setuid and think that may be a clue to it...

Answer (score 4):

**Option 1**: Make the top-level directory world-writable.
Remind users that permissions on the directories they create are ***THEIR*** responsibility as the owner of the directory.
Note that this lets users create more than one directory. Your users will eventually screw it up and make a mess (axiom: Users Are Dumb.)
*As you have correctly surmised, the [`sticky bit`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit) (`+t`, as found on `/tmp`) is important here: It keeps users from removing *other people's* directories, which they would be able to do if the top-level directory was world-writable *without* the sticky bit.*

**Option 2**: Make the top-level directory owned by root. Create a subdirectory for each user when you create their account.
You can set the permissions on the users' directories to whatever you want as a default (`0700` is a good start). Again, managing permissions on it after that is ***THEIR*** responsibility as the owner of the directory.
This keeps your users from making a mess of the top-level directory.  You can automate the directory creation bits as part of your user creation script (you DO use a script, right? :)

Comment: Awesome thank you. I also forgot to mention that this NAS is on a network with about an 80-20 ratio of windows users to linux users. Samba permissions come into play also

Comment: Samba permissions are a different (and substantially more complex) breed of beast.